# "Cookbook not found" error with ChefSpec test

Tags: rspec, berkshelf, chefspec

I'm trying to running my ChefSpec tests.

This is my ChefSpec test:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

describe 'my-demo::basesystem' do

  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe)}

  describe 'basesystem' do

    it "should be installed" do
      expect(chef_run).to install_package('build-essential')
    end
  end
end
```

And it is my recipe

```
include_recipe 'build-essential::default'
```

It was the error output when I executed my ChefSpec tests

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/d20140208-11211-1tu0tmq/my-demo/recipes/basesystem.rb
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
----------------------------------
Cookbook build-essential:: not found. If you're loading build-essential:: from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/d20140208-11211-1tu0tmq/build-essential/recipes/default.rb:21:in `from_file'
  /tmp/d20140208-11211-1tu0tmq/my-demo/recipes/basesystem.rb:2:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/d20140208-11211-1tu0tmq/build-essential/recipes/default.rb:

 14:  # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 15:  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 16:  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 17:  # limitations under the License.
 18:  #
 19:  
 20:  begin
 21>>   include_recipe "build-essential::#{node['platform_family']}"
 22:  rescue Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
 23:    Chef::Log.warn "A build-essential recipe does not exist for the platform_family: #{node['platform_family']}"
 24:  end
 25:  


Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook build-essential:: not found. If you're loading build-essential:: from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
/tmp/d20140208-11211-1tu0tmq/build-essential/recipes/default.rb:21:in `from_file'
/tmp/d20140208-11211-1tu0tmq/my-demo/recipes/basesystem.rb:2:in `from_file'
./spec/recipes/base_system_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./spec/recipes/base_system_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 0.062297226 seconds

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know what's the problem, I thought that Berkshelf could be resolve the cookbooks dependencies.

Comment: Please post your spec_helper as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the stacktrace:

```
20:  begin
21>>   include_recipe "build-essential::#{node['platform_family']}"
22:  rescue Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
23:    Chef::Log.warn "A build-essential recipe does not exist for the platform_family: #{node['platform_family']}"
24:  end
```

You'll see on line 21 that the build-essential cookbook is trying to load a recipe that corresponds to the current node's platform family. However, for ChefSpec, that data isn't set unless you specifically tell ChefSpec what kind of node to impersonate. In other words, `node['platform_family']` is `nil`, so it's trying to include a recipe named `build-essential::(nothing)`, and that's not valid.

To fix this, you can either set the value for platform_family:

```
let(chef_run) do
  ChefSpec::Runner.new do |node|
    node.automatic['platform_family'] = 'ubuntu'
  end.converge(described_recipe)
end
```

Or (preferred), you can tell ChefSpec to impersonate a node:

```
let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '12.04').converge(described_recipe) }
```